# Convert JSON response into list of objects and display in table in Windows Forms with vb.net

Tags: vb.net, windows-forms-designer

I have something like this to probe a server for a list of objects:

```
Public Class AllCustomers
    Private Sub AllCustomers_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Dim request = WebRequest.CreateHttp("http://****************/api/customer")
        request.Method = HttpMethod.Get.Method


        Dim response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
        Dim dataStream As Stream = response.GetResponseStream()
        Dim reader As New StreamReader(dataStream)
        Dim responseFromServer As String = reader.ReadToEnd()

    End Sub
End Class
```

It returns the following string (as an example):

```
[
    {
        "CustomerId": 1,
        "FirstName": "Rodrigo",
        "LastName": "Carvajal",
        "Age": 26
    },
    {
        "CustomerId": 2,
        "FirstName": "Rodrigo",
        "LastName": "Carvajal",
        "Age": 26
    },
    {
        "CustomerId": 3,
        "FirstName": "Rodrigo",
        "LastName": "Carvajal",
        "Age": 26
    }
]
```

Those attributes are actually from a Customer object. I want to convert this string into a list of Customers and then display them as rows in a table in a Windows Form. How do I convert the string into the list of objects?

Then, what would be an ideal way to display them in a table? is the DataGridView a good option? I read that I'd have to create a DataSet object as well. Is there another option?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I convert the string into the list of objects?

You can use [Json.net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

```
Dim customers As List(Of Customer) 
customers = JsonCovert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of Customer))(responseFromServer)
```

> Then, what would be an ideal way to display them in a table?

Add them to a data source the gird can bind to.

```
Dim list As BindingList(Of Customer) = new BindingList(Of Customer)(customers)
myGrid.DataSource = list
```

Or you could have just added the list as the customers list

```
myGrid.DataSource = customers
```

Comment: For this simple thing you can also use JavaScriptDeserializer, so you don't have to download anything. It's used in pretty much the same way.